# How do I listen for step up event for input type="number"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to listen to `<input type="number" />` step UP (increment) and step down events with jQuery. (currently I can only understand how to listen to change event)

[image]

Comment: Why exactly? This sounds like a problem which might not need to be solved with jQuery.

Comment: Maybe he is using jQuery on his website and then, he wants to use it for this code.

Answer (score 2):

For input type="number", you can use the change event, but will possibly have more cases to handle and create some clutter. I broke it down, I recommend using the "mouseup" event for the increment feature (which will mainly be used from pc) But if the user uses a device instead, I would use the event 'keyup' since the increment feature will not appear and the user will have an on-screen keyboard instead. The change event will listen for both.

For example :

```
$(".counter").bind('mouseup', function () { 

    if($(this).val() == undefined || $(this).val() == "")
            return; /* Exit dont bother with handling this later, if its not needed leave. */

    /* Important Check against integers and not strings. */
    /* Comparing against arrays will give unexecpted behavior, size is different then the value. */         
    var newVal = parseInt($(this).val());
    var oldVal = parseInt($(this).data('old-value'));

    if (oldVal < newVal) {      
        alert('incrementing');
    }
    else{

        alert('decrementing'); 
    }

    $(this).data('old-value', $(this).val());

});

$(".counter").bind('keyup', function () { 
    /* Similar logic */
});
```

I use "bind" instead of "on" or the by method "change" since "on" is a shorthand for bind.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rand0md/8qcxtf2m/5/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a listener of the stepUp and StepDown but you can externalize the PLUS and LESS buttons of the input number using:

```
document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(5); //increase the value +5
document.getElementById("myNumber").stepDown(5); // decrease the value -5
```

So you can finally achieve your objective!

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_number_stepup.asp

NOTE: Be aware that IE11 and EDGE doesn't implement stepUp / stepDown. On my case I just remove the + and - icon and leave only the input number field. Hope EDGE die soon...

Answer (score 2):

*I know this is a relatively old question but, came across it in my search.*

In case anyone comes here looking for the answer to this on a custom element triggering the `stepUp()` or `stepDown()` like me and not wanting to use jQuery, the below should help:

On the element handling the `click` to trigger the `stepUp()/stepDown()`, add this (and change the elements to whatever relation they have to each other):

```
onclick="this.elementToStepDown.stepDown();this.elementToStepDown.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))"
```

Fuller example:

```html
<input class="input--hide_controls" id="number_of_ducks" type="number" value="7" step="1"/>
    <div class="increment" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input').stepUp();this.parentNode.querySelector('input').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))"><i class="im im-plus"></i></div>
```

Or, extract it out and put it in a JS function that does the same and call that `onclick`:

```js
let increment = (element) => {
    element.stepUp();
    element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
}

let decrement = (element) => {
    element.stepDown();
    element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
}
```

Then listen out for the 'change' event on the input.

Answer (score 1):

There is no event for `up` and `down`. You can use `change` event

```
$(".counter").change(function () {
   alert($(this).val());      
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/4gjwZ/1/)

You can try something like, You can store previous value and compare with currently value and identify up or down

```
$(".counter").change(function () {
    if ($(this).data('old-value') < $(this).val()) {
        alert('Alert up');
    } else {
        alert('Alert dowm');
    }
    $(this).data('old-value', $(this).val());
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/4gjwZ/2/)

Comment: "(currently I can only understand how to listen to change event)"

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific event for `up` and `down`. Your closest bet is to use the `change` event. You might also take a look at the `oninput` event but I am not sure it is supported by all browsers:

```
$('#myinput').on('input', function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
var $counter = $("your_counter");
var number = $counter.val();

$counter.change(function () {
   if($counter.val() > number)
       alert('up');
   else
       alert('down');
   number = $counter.val();
});
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6bb8S/

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<input type="number" data-number="0" class="counter" value="0" />
```

you need to put the same value in the data-number and in the value

jquery

```
$(document).on('change', '.counter', function() {

//get number of input
var number = $(this).attr("data-number");

//console.log(number);

if($(this).val() > number){
    alert('up');
}else{
    alert('down');
}

//set number of input for the next step
$(this).attr("data-number", $(this).val());

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/maicon_card/46hdm8pj/

works with multiple inputs