# Making the step act as a guide in <input type="number">

Tags: javascript, html, input

How could I make the step attribute for an `<input type="number">` act more of a guide, so I could input any positive integer but the increment arrows would change the current value by a fixed amount?

e.g. I could enter 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...
and the step would increment the values as 0,6,12,18,24,... etc...

I could implement this if I knew how to capture the step up/step down events in JavaScript. However, I can't find a way to do that. I've shown exactly what I'd like in the pseudo code below:

```
<input id="num" type="number">
<script>
  inp = document.getElementById("num");
  var increment = 6;
  if ( step up pressed ){
    inp.value += increment;
  }
  else if  (step down pressed ){
    inp.value -= increment;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think step fires a specific event. Someone here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662352/how-do-i-listen-for-step-up-event-for-input-type-number?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa  made the recommendation of just using the (change) event, storing the last value, and comparing it to the new value to determine change direction and then increment accordingly.

Comment: Ahh ok, I just assumed there would be an in-built method for this.

Comment: I would assume the same. Its a little surprising there isn't. The 'step' functionality seems a bit crippled the way it is currently

Comment: I've added an answer based on the question you posted. I think it will do but it certainly seems like a bit of a hack!

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
<input id="num" type="number" step="6">
```

Comment: No, as the step locks the set of numbers that can be inputted as multiples of the step  i.e. if the step is 6 then only 0,6,12,18,24,30,... can be inputted. However, I would like to be able to input all numbers (while also incrementing the value by something larger than 1).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a horrible hack but here's an answer to my question:

```
<input id='num' type=number step=0.00001 onchange="increment()">

<script>
    document.prev_num = document.getElementById("num").value;
    function increment() {
      var step = 6;
      var catch_step = 0.00001;
      var curr_num = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num").value);
      if ( Math.abs(curr_num - (document.prev_num + catch_step)) < 1e-7 ){
        curr_num  = curr_num - catch_step + step;
      }
      else if (Math.abs(curr_num - (document.prev_num - catch_step)) < 1e-7){
        curr_num = curr_num + catch_step - step;
      }
      else if (curr_num != parseInt(curr_num)){
        alert("You can only input integers.")
        curr_num = parseInt(curr_num);
      }
      document.getElementById("num").value = curr_num;
      document.prev_num = curr_num;
    }
</script>
```

So HTML forces the numbers to be multiples of 0.00001, which includes all integers.

Javascript then acts when the number is changed. If that change is only a change of 0.000001 the step button was almost certainly pressed.

Non integers won't be accepted.