# Number Input Accept value fewer than step

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

My step is 1000, I want to change the value of the input by step, but also accept values like: (800,5500,...)

```html
<input type="number" step="1000">
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662352/how-do-i-listen-for-step-up-event-for-input-type-number Seems you'll have to change the values manually

Answer (score 1):

The number state represents a control for setting the element's value to a string representing a number.

The value attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a valid floating point number.

**autocomplete**  on/ off/ default

- *on*

  The on state indicates that the value is not particularly sensitive
  and the user can expect to be able to rely on his user agent to
  remember values he has entered for that control.
- *off*

  The off state indicates either that the control's input data is
  particularly sensitive (for example the activation code for a nuclear
  weapon); or that it is a value that will never be reused (for example
  a one-time-key for a bank login) and the user will therefore have to
  explicitly enter the data each time, instead of being able to rely on
  the UA to prefill the value for him; or that the document provides
  its own autocomplete mechanism and does not want the user agent to
  provide autocompletion values.
- *default*

  The default state indicates that the user agent is to use the
  autocomplete attribute on the element's form owner instead. (By
  default, the autocomplete attribute of form elements is in the on
  state.)

**list**

ID reference

Identify an element that lists predefined options suggested to the user.
If present, its value must be the ID of a datalist element in the same document.

**max**

valid floating point number

indicate the allowed range of values for the element.

**min**

valid floating point number

indicate the allowed range of values for the element.

**name**

string

Gives the name of the input element.

**readonly**

boolean

Controls whether or not the user can edit the form control.

**required**

boolean

When specified, the element is required.

**step**

any/ positive floating-point number

Specifies the value granularity of the element’s value.

**value**

string

Gives the default value of the input element.

Answer (score 0):

u need to write validation..u can try like below..

```
<input type="number" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" step="1000">
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are allowed to disable the keypress, then use

```
$("[type='number']").keypress(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```