# event listener added within function expression executes immediately

Tags: jquery, event-handling

Can someone please explain why this event listener added within a function expression is executed immediately?

```js
fmperror = function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('body').on('click', function() {
    $('body').off('click');
    // normally trigger log out of website here.
    // but call alert to similulate log out intention.
    alert('log out');
  });
};

$(".line-ord-qty").on("change", function (e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  // show error message here normally.
  // set up event handler so that any click
  fmperror(e);
});
```

```css
body { height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <label>OrdQty</label>
  <input class='line-ord-qty' type='number' min='100' step='100' value='100' size='5'>

</body>
```

[CODEPEN:](https://codepen.io/kbrfuller/pen/gOWVoxX)

Comment: It isn’t executed immediately.

Comment: Hello Sebastian, when fmperror() is invoked I want the event handler added, but it executes immediately.  You have to make a change to the numeric input first to invoke fmperror().

Comment: Also what exactly are you trying to do with this code? The attaching of an event handler and then immediately calling it and removing it is a *very* weird thing to be doing. Perhaps `one()` is what you need? Or delegation using `on()` instead?

Comment: It happens 'immediately' because the `change` event fires, is handled, adds the `click` event handler, `click` event handler fires and bubbles up the DOM, the new event handler runs and then unbinds itself. As mentioned above, this is an odd thing to do which I'm sure can be done in a much better way if you can explain your goal.

Comment: Rory, its sort of complicated.  This is simulated our B2B site and parts and prices with selling uom displayed via ajax.  The input step value has been reported by a customer to sometimes change once in a blue moon.  That particular error I track and force a session log out.  I don't want the event sticking around after they log back in.

Comment: You really should be working with the `input` event, not the `change` event, when using `<input type="number">`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon there are slight differences in behaviour between `change` and `input`. Depending on the OPs use case there may be a legitimate reason for using one over the other.

Comment: Let me explain a bit further. when the input qty changes, I compare the current step value off that input to what the step value was when it was orginally saved at the ajax call.  The comparison of the 2 step value is done at the time of the input 'change' event. if found to be different then a error message is display and fmperror is called to add the  'click' anywhere on the page and force a logout.  You notice I remove the event immediately afterwards so that the event is not accumulated.

Comment: Sebastian. I work with 'change' event for up/down arrow detection in numeric input... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662352/how-do-i-listen-for-step-up-event-for-input-type-number

Comment: It's not executed immediately.  It's executed when/because you click out of the input to get the change event to fire.  You click outside the input -> change event followed immediately by click event.  Your `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` only applies to the change event not *all* events.   Try this:  click in the input, type a value then press *tab* to exit the input - no alert - click anywhere inside the snippet (as tab exits the snippet) - click event fires as you've clicked.

Comment: It *is* accumulated: Try this: click inside the input, change it, tab out, now shift-tab back into the input, change it again, repeat - now click outside the textbox -> multiple alerts.  Fix by adding `$('body').off('click');` *before* `$('body').on('click'...` (as well as inside)

Comment: Lame fix/hack for the "immedate" click event, which everyone will jump on and say don't do this:  `setTimeout(() => fmperror(e), 1);`.   Don't do this.  Fix the actual issue.

Comment: @kruddock Yes, but the `input` event works, too, and is more flexible. If the arrows are used, the event’s `inputType` is `"insertReplacementText"`.

Answer (score 2):

It **isn't** executed immediately. You probably click on the arrow provided by the browser to change the value? If that is the case, the click event will be triggered as you click on the `<body>`.

Also, it is not exactly clear what you are trying to do. The current behavior of your code is that when the value of the field changes, `click` events will accumulate on `$("body")`. Eventually, if you click on `<body>`, multiple identical events will be triggered sequentially, which is very strange.

Comment: How can you say that this added event -> $('body').on('click', function() Is not excuted immediately? when the function expression is invoked the intent is to create this event handler, and not have it is executed immediately.

Comment: @kruddock Also the event will still be accumulated despite what you mentioned in the comments since you detach it before other click events that are still "in queue" have been processed

Comment: Try to change the value of the field by using arrow keys on keyboard and click on the body, you will see alerts firing one by one.

Comment: Try changing the value then **tab** out, without clicking anywhere - the click event isn't fired - therefore it isn't fired immediately.   It's firing because you're clicking and the click event runs *after* the change event.

Comment: @freedomn-m.  Your comments about the click event firing after the change event helped me sort this one out.  Have it working the way I want.  I just needed to capture the click event and stop the propogation of it making its way into my fmperror(). https://codepen.io/kbrfuller/pen/gOWVVqv